# 'If object is None' not behaving as expected

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, nonetype

Writing an analytics script for facebook chats with python. The library I'm using (fbchat) sometimes returns None type objects in place of messages. I thought I could catch this with a simple

```
   if message is None:
      continue
```

in my loop through my message list. However, I'm still getting exceptions due to the object being None type. What am I doing wrong here?

Code snippet:

```
for message in messages:
            #sometimes the fbchat library doesn't return a message
            if message is None:
                continue

            #strip the line endings to not mess up the csv
            message.text.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Exact exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collect.py", line 58, in <module>
    message.text.replace('\n', ' ')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Can you add the exception exact message?

Comment: Is your `message` `None` or is the `message.text` `None`?

Comment: I thought the whole object would be None but it seems only the text property is. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `message.text is None` resolves the issue and is what I should have done in the first place.